# How do I automatically update a local storage data

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to automatically update a data sent from another JS file using localStorage `setItem()` and `getItem()`. I tried using the `setInterval()` method to automatically refresh the data so I can get the recent data without reloading the page, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

File A:

```js
document.getElementById('submit')
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    var weight = document.form.weight.value;
    localStorage.setItem('weight4page2', weight);
  });
```

File B:

```js
const weight = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('weight4page2'));
const weightUpdated = setInterval(weight, 3000);

console.log(weight);
// I get the user inputted weight from JS file A
console.log(weightUpdated);
```

So I get `1` instead of the input value from file A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log `console.log(weightUpdated)` in file B, you log the `intervalID` returned from `setInterval()`. This is a numeric value which identifies the timer and which can be later used to cancel the interval using `clearInterval()`.

File A looks somewhat OK, but in file B there are a couple of errors.

First, you don't pass a function to the `setInterval()` method but a number. You should pass a function where you could get the updated item from the `localStorage`. Second, you should log the retrieved item from here, not outside of this function. Check out the code below:

```js
function getWeightFromLS() {
  const weight = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("weight4page2"));
  console.log({ time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), weight });

  return weight;
}

// return id to cancel
const intervalID = setInterval(getWeightFromLS, 3000);
```

I also created a sandbox for you, so you can check it in live: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-submit-localstorage-2z79s

A better approach would be to use the pubsub pattern instead of this `setInterval()`;

Comment: Thanks @Zsolt Meszaros.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is useful for you, could you please accept it as answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Comment: How do I do that as am new in stack

Comment: There is a checkmark you can click on next to my question. If you need more help, you can check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: I have another question. Actually, I charted the weight in a speedometer chart in another HTML page. So when the user in File A enters a new input and clicks submit, after 3 secs, there will be a change in the speedometer chart at file B. Then my problem now is that the speedometer arrow falls back to zero and back to the last weight value every 3 secs...instead of being static at the last weight value till a new weight value is submitted

Comment: Do you have a sandbox I can check somewhere?

Comment: No, actually am new to programming, still learning some basics, so I don't know how to use sandbox